# How to pass values from CDK into a lambda

Tags: python, typescript, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, opensearch

I am trying to create a service that employs a Lambda function and an opensearch domain. I have one cdk stack typescript file that creates all my service instances and I want to pass the endpoint for the opensearch domain into the Lambda, but I don't know how. I can't do this until the domain is created since the endpoint differs based on each deployment of the CDK. My lambda files are referenced through a url, is there a way that I can import a file for my lambda function while defining a variable to be used in that function?

Comment: Use environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

I am not that familiar with opensearch and you have provided no example code so this is a bit awkward to answer but when you create something using a CDK constructor it returns an object of a particular class type.  That means you should be able to read the properties of the object.  Looking at the opensearch.Domain class it has a domain_endpoint property.

Looking at the constructor code [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-opensearchservice.Domain.html) (note the version and links to different languages)

```
const domain = new opensearch.Domain(this, 'Domain', {
  version: opensearch.EngineVersion.OPENSEARCH_1_0,
  ebs: {
    volumeSize: 100,
    volumeType: ec2.EbsDeviceVolumeType.GENERAL_PURPOSE_SSD,
  },
  nodeToNodeEncryption: true,
  encryptionAtRest: {
    enabled: true,
  },
});
```

You should be able to get the domain property using `domain.domainEndpoint`

However, I don't see how you will be able to use that as a CDK variable for your lambda.  It looks like you need to use a [custom end point](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-opensearchservice.Domain.html#customendpoint) and the documentation talks about how to provide that in the constructor.